# Howto react to local notification in the currently running view

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have a web app, that is running partly in background mode (at least for the time, iOS does allow that).
When an event occurs inside it, I ifre a local notification.
When the user clicks on it, the app comes back to the foreground, but I want to call some javascript function inside the web app.
How do I call a function inside my view controller from the app delegate's
application:didReceiveLocalNotification method?

Comment: You can raise one notification from inside application:didReceiveLocalNotification ann add your viewcontroller as an observer. Once you view controller receives the notification you can do your stuff then

Answer (score 0):

Assuming myViewController as the rootViewController you can use:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *) application.delegate;
[delegate.window.rootViewController launchJavascriptMethod];
```